# Is there an accepted definition for differentiating sets?

Tags: general-topology, derivatives

Is there an accepted theory for calculus of sets?

For example, we have a set $A_t$ which changes through time, how is the set's derivative defined?

I apologise that the question is quite vague, but I don't know how to make it any more specific.

Comment: Well, could you give us an example of the sort of family $A_t$ you have in mind?

Comment: Well for example could $A_t$ be the sigma algebra generated by the random process $X_t$ at time $t$?

Comment: Ah.  I don't think you'll find a good notion of the derivative of that sort of thing.  Really, it's hard to imagine what you might hope for.  Derivatives depend on a topology...you have to say when two values are "close".  Families of abstract sets don't generally come with a topology.  Not to say that there might not be special cases of interest.

Comment: Could you provide a special case of interest? Or somewhere I could read up on some?

Comment: I can't think of one!  That's why I asked you what you were thinking of.  I thought it possible that the specific context would suggest a definition.  As a rule, I'd advise;  don't start by looking for a definition. If a construction arises naturally in the context of some problem, that construction might give rise to a general definition.

Comment: Well, if $A_t=\{f(t)\}, t\in \Bbb R$ is a family of sets, we could define $\dot A_t:=\{f'(t)\}$. Provided $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: Maybe financial weapons of mass destru—I mean, maybe the calculus of [stochastic processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_process) is close to what you want? (Bad joke, I know).